# How to check in s3-outbound-gateway if the bucket is available in S3 storage

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-integration, aws-api-gateway, spring-integration-aws

How to check in s3-outbound-gateway if the bucket is available in S3 storage before processing using bucket expression. If the bucket is not available, it should be redirected to errorchannel.

```
   <int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway id="FileGenerationChannelS3"
    request-channel="filesOutS3ChainChannel"
    reply-channel="filesArchiveChannel"
    transfer-manager="transferManager"
    bucket-expression="headers.TARGET_BUCKET"
    command="UPLOAD">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway>` is a typical `MessageHandler`-based event-driven consumer. There can be applied an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with a desired `failureChannel` in the `<int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>`.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) for more info.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. can u suggest some sample code to check if s3 bucket is available?